# Bidirectional communication between two applications on the same port and host

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, port, bidirectional

I have two applications **on the same host** and I try to create a bidirectional communication between them but **on the same port**.

```
                          Port: 8080
|               | <-----------------------> |               |  
| Application 1 |   send/receive messages   | Application 2 |
|               | <-----------------------> |               |
                          Port: 8080
```

I am aware that this is possible using websockets. The difficulty is that I need to use UDP and as far as I know websockets only work with TCP.

If it is possible, is it possible with NodeJS or Python?

Comment: Only one program can bind to a certain port

Comment: When I open two terminals and type `nc -ul 127.0.0.1 8080` and in the other `nc -u 127.0.0.1 8080` I can, for some reason, type in either one of them and the message will appear in the other terminal. How does this work?

Comment: The `nc -u` command chooses a random port for its own end, and sends messages to port 8080

Comment: Ah okay, thank you.